# Relation between eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^H$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^H$ are related?

My approach :

If $A^H=A$ then eigenvalues of $A^H$ and $A$ would be same. This will require the eigenvalues to be real. since $Ax_1=u_1x_1$ when we take the transpose of each side

$u_1^H$ is the conjugate of $u_1$

$x_1^HA^Hx_1=u_1^Hx_1^Hx_1$

$x^HA^Hx_1=u_1^Hx_1$

Somehow that could be de

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Jordan normal forms of $A$ and $A^H$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hypothesis that $A^H$ is complex-conjugated and transposed matrix $A$ (commonly denoted $A^*$), we can write (suppose that $x$ is an eigenvalue of $A^*$)

$$0=\det (A^*-xI) = \det((\bar A)^T-xI^T) = \det(\bar A - xI) = \overline {\det(A-\bar x I)} = \det (A-\bar xI).$$

This implies that the eigenvalues of the matrix $A^*$ are complex conjugates of eigenvalues of the matrix $A$.

Comment: I assume here by $A^H$ you mean the same as $A^*$. Anyway, the one step that is maybe not 100% obvious is that $\det(\overline{B})=\overline{\det(B)}$.

Comment: @Ian, yes, I explicitly said so in the first phrase of my answer that $A^H\equiv A^*$. The identity $\det(\bar B)=\overline{\det B}$ is a d irect corollary of basic properties of complex conjugation ($\overline{x+y}=\bar x +\bar y$, $\overline{xy}=\bar x\bar y$) and of the definition of determinant.